# SwiftUI: Launch 2 views (one over the other) at once, using single animation, or no animation at all

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Scenario:**

`MainView` has a button which should do the following:

- Launch a `ThirdPartyView`. That view is a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` over the legacy `UINavigationController`, if it matters
- Once a `ThirdPartyView` is dismissed, launch `MyThirdPartyIntegrationView` with some information provided by a `ThirdPartyView`

**Goal:**

I want to transition *seamlessly* from MainView to ThirdPartyView, and then from ThirdPartyView to MyThirdPartyIntegrationView.

**Complications:**

- I cannot change anything about how ThirdPartyView: I cannot change how it dismisses itself, or how it launches itself. In reality it's a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` over some legacy `UINavigationController` (with some self-contained flow).
- The ThirdPartyView communicates information back in a delegate asynchronously. I cannot use `@Binding` between those views.
- The solution has to be iOS 15 compatible.
- The ThirdPartyView has its own navigation (which I think excludes things like adding it as an overlay or a view inside MyThirdPartyIntegrationView, but feel free to coeect me on that).

So by now I tried 2 approaches:

**Approach 1** - MainView launches ThirdPartyView as `fullScreenCover` and MainView's ViewModel acts as ThirdPartyView's delegate. Once ThirdPartyView is done, MainView then launches MyThirdPartyIntegrationView and passes an info from ThirdPartyView as a @Binding.

The problems with that solution were:

- There was a visible gap between ThirdPartyView closure and MyThirdPartyIntegrationView appearance.
- And MainView's ViewModel has to play a role of ThirdPartyView's delegate, although it has nothing to do with information received, it merely passes it to MyThirdPartyIntegrationView.

So an improved approach was

**Approach 2** - MainView launches MyThirdPartyIntegrationView as a `fullScreenCover`, which immediately launches ThirdPartyView as its `fullScreenCover`, and also MyThirdPartyIntegrationView's ViewModel now acts as a delegate. When info is received, and ThirdPartyView is gone, the MyThirdPartyIntegrationView shows up immediately.

This solution solves both issues with the first solution, but its problem is that in the beginning you can see both views launching: from MainView to MyThirdPartyIntegrationView, and from MyThirdPartyIntegrationView to ThirdPartyView.

Here's the code that replicates the issue (note that I've made ThirdPartyView simple only for this example, as it seems doesn't matter what type of view it is - most importantly it cannot change).

```
// MARK: - Third-Party View simulation. The code inside this view is unchangeable

struct ThirdPartyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var info: String = ""
    
    // Simulate a delegate called upon view completion.
    var delegate: (String) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Input value:", text: $info)
            Divider()
            Text("Your Value is:").font(.body.bold())
            Text(info).font(.body.italic())
            Button("Done") {
                // Primitive way to simulate async call to delegate at the end of the flow
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    self.delegate(info)
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Integration. This code can be changed in any way to serve the goal

@MainActor class MyThirdPartyIntegrationViewModel: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var thirdPartyInfo = ""
    
    // Updates property on main thread
    private func update(_ value: String) {
        thirdPartyInfo = value
    }
    
    // Provided to ThirdPartyView, not isolated
    nonisolated func onThirdPartyInfo(_ value: String) {
        Task.detached { @MainActor in
            self.update(value)
        }
    }
}

struct MyThirdPartyIntegrationView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = MyThirdPartyIntegrationViewModel()
    // Cause the launch of fullScreenCover immediately
    @State var launchThirdParty = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Third party said:").font(.body.bold())
            Text(viewModel.thirdPartyInfo).font(.body.italic())
            Button("Done") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
        // HERE: Launches the ThirdPartyView
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $launchThirdParty) {
            ThirdPartyView(delegate: viewModel.onThirdPartyInfo)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Main View. Ideally it should just launch integration, but other options are possible too.

struct MainView: View {
    
    @State var shouldLaunch = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Launch") {
                shouldLaunch = true
            }
        }
        // HERE: Launches the MyThirdPartyIntegrationView
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shouldLaunch) {
            MyThirdPartyIntegrationView()
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I am looking for an alternative to `fullScreenCover` over `fullScreenCover` which allows

- Either a way to launch 2 views at once, using single animation
- Or no animation at all, both screens just appear at once

Or maybe a better approach all together, if you think there's a better way to accomplish this scenario. Thanks in advance.